# Python, Convert Arbitrary List of Floats to Decimals with Most Precision without Rounding Errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, rounding, rounding-error

I'm writing code that has to take a bunch of floats in Python and convert them to decimals without any rounding errors but with as much precision as possible. I'm not sure what the best approach to solve this is. Just based on some empirical tests, this seems to work OK:

```
import math
from decimal import Decimal
numbers = [2400.2, 4800.3, 3000, 1.1 + 2.2, 0.000000000000006, -1.418686791445350, 1.418686791445356666666, 2400.418686791445350]

def orderOfMagnitude(number):
  return math.floor(math.log(abs(number), 10))

for num in numbers:
  places = 14 - orderOfMagnitude(num)
  dec = Decimal(num).quantize(Decimal(f'1.{"0"*places}'))
  print(dec)
```

output:

```
2400.20000000000
4800.30000000000
3000.00000000000
3.30000000000000
6.00000000000000E-15
-1.41868679144535
1.41868679144536
2400.41868679145
```

but of course there could be a counterexample where this doesn't work and there is an error.  For example, if I use 15 instead of 14 in the formula for `places` I get:

```
2400.200000000000
4800.299999999999
3000.000000000000
3.300000000000000
6.000000000000000E-15
-1.418686791445350
1.418686791445357
2400.418686791445
```

and you can see the error for `4800.3`.

What is the proper way to convert an arbitrary list of floats to decimals with as much precision as possible without rounding errors? Is this even possible?

Edit:
I'm on Windows 10 and Python 3.8 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Although the question states an interest in converting “floats” to decimals, the examples suggest you are interested in reproducing the decimal numerals in source code in output. If the floating-point format used is IEEE-754 “double precision”, which is common, then a rule for this is that if any decimal numeral of 15 significant digits or fewer is converted to the floating-point format with round-to-nearest, then converting the floating-point number to decimal with 15 significant digits reproduces the original number as long as there is no overflow or underflow.

Comment: Some of the numerals in your examples have more than 15 digits. Once a number is converted to the floating-point format, the floating-point number contains no information about how many digits there originally were. So there cannot be any algorithm to print the original numerals given only the floating-point number. For the others, formatting the number with 15 significant digits will reproduce the original number. That is 15 significant digits total, not some number after the decimal point.

Comment: Python probably has some “g” output format for that; taking the log to set the digit count is generally not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
from decimal import Decimal
numbers = [2400.2, 4800.3, 3000, 1.1 + 2.2, 0.000000000000006, -1.418686791445350, 1.418686791445356666666, 2400.418686791445350]

def orderOfMagnitude(number):
  return math.floor(math.log(abs(number), 10))

for num in numbers:
  places = 15 - orderOfMagnitude(num)
  dec = Decimal(num).quantize(Decimal(f'1.{"0"*places}'))
  print(dec)
```

works well

```
2400.200000000000
4800.300000000000
3000.000000000000
3.300000000000000
6.000000000000000E-15
-1.418686791445350
1.418686791445357
2400.418686791445
```

Comment: What system are you on? I'm on Windows 10. I wonder if that makes a difference. I get the rounding error when I use 15.

Comment: my current os is linux and python v3.8

Comment: it already worked on windows too